# How to downscale retina image loaded from remote server for non retina iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, scale, retina-display

I have to load icons for my app from a remote source, the images are 50x50px to be displayed on the devices at 25x25px.

At the moment the icons are showing the correct size on retina devices but twice the size on non retina devices.

FYI: There is no way for the remote source to supply non retina images.

How can I scale-down the UIImage on non-retina devices, so that all devices display the same size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First check if you have Retina display

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){
```

then you'll need to set the scale option of the image:

```
UIImage * scaledImage = [UIImage alloc];
scaledImage = [[scaledImage initWithCGImage:[resourceImage CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp] autorelease];
```

Then i believe the imageView should scale it and display correctly

Comment: Close but no cigar. Firstly the if statement is detecting only retina devices and then doubling the artwork again. I need the reverse, I download the high-res version from remote source and need to downscale not upscale.

Comment: The if statement is given for reference, not copying, i hope it is clear that you can reverse it or use `else` branch. The original code downscales the image and the Retina/not-Retina logic is something you can do yourself, right ? This snippet only shows the downscale operation and the decision rule.

Comment: You're right. Removing the `if` statement fixed it. I need to always set the scale to 2.0 for my remote images as they are all retina sized.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
+ (UIImage *) onScaleImage:(UIImage *)image width:(int)width
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    NSUInteger nWidth = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    if (nWidth == width)
        return (nil);

    double dScaleFactor = (double)width / (double)nWidth;

    NSUInteger nHeight = (int)((double)CGImageGetHeight(imageRef) * dScaleFactor);

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, nHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);

    CGContextDrawImage (context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, nHeight), imageRef);
    CGImageRef imageRefScaled = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    // caller must retain
    UIImage *imageScaled = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRefScaled];

    CGContextRelease (context);
    CGImageRelease (imageRefScaled);

    return (imageScaled);
}
```

Comment: @A-Live answer is surely easier solution, for iOS4+, though scale would be 0.5 not 2.0 since you're downscaling.  Above works on older iOS versions

Comment: I like @A-Live's answer but it does not downscale, it upscales, and even 0.5 upscaled the image.

Comment: @CSmith thank you for the comment, it must be 2.0 factor as this parameter is used to declare the source image factor: `The scale factor to use when interpreting the image data.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just wrap every call to it in an if statement, like so:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    //do scale stuff here
}
```

To avoid typing this every time, you could declare a category on UIScreen, which uses this code inside a -realScale method or something.